Chess FEN/EPD/PGN mirroring?
I am looking for a tool which is able to automatically convert a chess FEN/EPD/PGN file with 100+ positions into
a) a file with the same positions but different side to move, or
b) a file with the same positions, but mirrored horizontally (White becomes Black, and Black becomes White) , or
c) any similar alteration producing a new interesting position from the original one.

